# Making Player Jump

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, eclipse

I have been editing a piece of code and I have already implemented gravity so I would like to know how i could make the player jump when the screen is touched. I would like the player bucket to jump. Here is my code you tell me how I add this to it.

```
public class Drop implements ApplicationListener {

Texture dropImage;
Texture bucketImage;
Sound dropSound;
Music rainMusic;

float GRAVITY  = -5f;

OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

Rectangle bucket;
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
long lastDropTime;

@Override
public void create() {  
    // load the image for the droplet and the bucket, 48X48 pixels each
    dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("drop.png"));
    bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

    //load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
    dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
    rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));

    //start the playback of the background music immediately
    rainMusic.setLooping(true);
    rainMusic.play();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,800,480);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    bucket = new Rectangle();
    bucket.x = 250;
    bucket.y= GRAVITY;
    bucket.width = 100;
    bucket.height = 100;        

    raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRaindrop();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener#dispose()
 */
@Override
public void dispose() {
    dropImage.dispose();
    bucketImage.dispose();
    dropSound.dispose();
    rainMusic.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0x64/255.0f, 0x95/255.0f, 0xed/255.0f, 
             0xff/255.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(bucketImage,bucket.x,bucket.y);
    for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops){
        batch.draw(dropImage,raindrop.x,raindrop.y);
    }
    batch.end();



    if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 900000000) spawnRaindrop();

    moveRainDrop();
}

private void moveRainDrop() {
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(raindrop.x + 48 < 0) iter.remove();

        if(raindrop.overlaps(bucket)){
            dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}

private void spawnRaindrop(){
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.y = MathUtils.random(0,450-48);
    raindrop.x = 800;
    raindrop.width = 110;
    raindrop.height = 100;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}


}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `bucket.y` only sets the buckets position, so that should not be -.5, it should be the bottom of the screen (0), or at least the ground, to start. To move the bucket you should add a method called `jumpBucket()` or something similar. Then call that method whenever a touch is performed (check this within your `render()` method). This method should add some sort of y-directional speed (stored as a variable in your class) to the bucket and, if you want, set a boolean called `isBucketJumping` to true.

Then to apply gravity: you generally want similar gravity between all objects on the screen, but since you probably want the raindrops to move without acceleration, you can just leave the `moveRainDrop()` method alone (although you shouldn't use *magic numbers*, like the 48 and 200; instead use a constant for the 200 and use `raindrop.height` for the 48). Make a `moveBucket()` method and whenever `isBucketJumping == true` move the bucket upwards by it's y speed and then subtract your gravity value from it's y speed. By playing around with the value for gravity and the balloon's initial y-directional speed you should be able get the bucket to hop as you want it to.

```
// in your render method
if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
{
   bucketJump();
}
moveBucket(); // this method will be called every tick

// in your bucketJump() method
isBucketJumping = true;
bucketYSpeed = 100;

// in your moveBucket() method
if(isBucketJumping())
{
   bucket.y += bucketYSpeed;
   bucketYSpeed -= GRAVITY;

   if(bucketHitGround()) // I purposely left out the method in this if statement for you to do as practice
   {
      isBucketJumping = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do it to see if I am doing it right. Please

Comment: @user3475907 I gave you a little example :)